# How can one calculate $U_n$ in function of $n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given $U_n$ numerical sequence such that :

$U_0=-\frac{1}{2}$

$U_{n+1}=\frac{U_n}{3-2U_n}$

The problem is how to calculate $U_n$ in function of $n$ .

In this exercise its given the numerical sequence $V_n=\frac{U_n}{U_n-1}$ then we have to show that $V_n$ is geometric sequence

So after that it becomes easy to calculate $U_n$ in function of $n$

Can I arrive to calculate $U_n$ in function of $n$ without giving the sequence $V_n$ ? And can I arrives to make my own sequence $W_n$ wich I can calculate by it $U_n$ in function of $n$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Show that $u_n\neq 0$.

Letting $t_n=\frac{1}{u_n}$, the recurrence relation rewrites as $\dfrac{1}{t_{n+1}}=\dfrac{1}{3t_n-2}$, or equivalentely, $3t_n-2=t_{n+1}$ with $t_0=-2$ which yields $t_n=1-3^{n+1}$.

Comment: How did you arrive to think about $\frac{1}{U_n}$

Comment: $3u_{n+1}-2u_nu_{n+1}=u_n$. Then $3u_{n+1}-u_n=2u_nu_{n+1}$ and finally, known $u_n\neq 0$ for all $n$, $\frac{3}{u_n}-\frac{1}{u_{n+1}}=2$